# How to prove a property in the set partitions problem

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition, combinatorial-proofs

Let $S(m,n)$ denote the set of all partitions of $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ into exactly $n$ non-empty subsets. How to prove that $S(m,2) = 2^n$ for all integer $m \geq 1$ ?

Comment: Did you mean $2^m$ where you wrote $2^n$?

Comment: Actually, $S(m,2)=2^{m-1}-1$. This is the number of ways to choose any proper subset of $\{2,\dots,m\}$ to be in the same subset as $1$.

Comment: Probably the reason for the down-votes is lack of what is considered to be "context", a concept that is not very precisely defined except when it means "Don't copy a homework problem without telling us your own thoughts about it." $\qquad$

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume you meant $S(m,2) = 2^m$ where you wrote $S(m,2) = 2^n.$

In how many ways can one partition a set of $4$ things into $2$ non-empty subsets?

\begin{align}
& 1/234 \\
& 2/134 \\
& 3/124 \\
& 4/123 \\
& 12/34 \\
& 13/24 \\
& 14/23
\end{align}
There are seven ways. That's less than $2^4=16.$ So the proposed proposition is false.

One thing that may make someone think it's true is that the number of subsets is $2^m,$ which in this case is $2^4=16,$ and then take each subset and its complement to form a partition. This overlooks two facts: $(1)$ Note that $12/34,$ the partition corresponding to the subset $\{1,2\},$ is not a different partition from the one corresponding to the subset $\{3,4\},$ and similarly for the other subsets of size $2,$ and the parition corresponding to $\{1\}$ is not different from that corresponding to $\{2,3,4\},$ although these are obviously different subset, and $(2)$ the empty set is one of the $2^4=16$ subsets but is not included in this enumeration of partitions.

Actually the number you need is $2^{n-1} -1.$ That can be seen as follows: There are $2^n$ subsets. Exclude the empty set and its complement, getting $2^n-2.$ Then observe that it takes two of the remaining sets to make a partition, so divide that by $2.$